# How to Open PDF in terminal using Shell Script?

Tags: command-line, gnome, java, files, filesystem

I am newbie to ubuntu :)

I need to open a pdf file from java program. The problem I am facing is, the java program detects the OS and calls corresponding file, For example: in Windows `.bat`, in Linux `.sh` etc..

I have written a `.sh` file in which I have written `gnome-open` and the path will be added from the java program. Here's how it looks from java:

```
/home/goodyzain/workspace/XYZ/TerminalTool/src/test/scripts/acrord32.sh /p /h /home/goodyzain/Downloads/goodyzain.pdf
```

This is the command which is passed to terminal. It gives this error even in terminal:

```
Usage: gnome-open <url>
```

**But**  if I write `gnome-open  /p /h /home/goodyzain/Downloads/goodyzain.pdf` it works.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what does the script look like?

Comment: Just have gnome-open :P

Comment: @muru thats the mistake :( I dont know how it should look like,BTW the path will be from java program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write a script which simply passes arguments on to another command, then use:

```
#! /bin/sh
gnome-open "$@"
```

`"$@"` expands to the arguments, exactly as passed.

It might be easier to just create a link to `gnome-open` with the name that your program expects:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/gnome-open /home/goodyzain/workspace/XYZ/TerminalTool/src/test/scripts/acrord32.sh
```

Comment: OMG its so funny...but i learned something new :)